# Hiding a xaml element but also be able to render using RenderTargetBitmap in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, z-index, visibility, rendertargetbitmap

I am using `RenderTargetBitmap` to capture the content of a control in XAML.
I am aware of using Visibility="Collapse" that would hide the control, but when the control is collapsed then `RenderTargetBitmap` renders a blank image, because according to the docs

> Content that's in the tree but with its Visibility set to Collapsed
>   won't be captured.

and

> Content that can't be captured will appear as blank in the captured
>   image, but other content in the same visual tree can still be captured
>   and will render (the presence of content that can't be captured won't
>   invalidate the entire capture of that XAML composition).

However I don't want to display it on the screen.

I was looking for something like a z-index or a layer, so I don't display it but still be able to capture that element.

Alternatively some other way that does not use `RenderTargetBitmap` that renders the element even though the `visibility` is set to `collapse`

Comment: Did you ever find an appropriate solution for this? I have a very similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Grid` as it stacks the elements. If you place an element at first it will be visually stacked below the second one only if they are in same row or column. In the sample below **RedGrid** is visualy below the **WhiteGrid**. So, you cannot visualy see it. But when you use RenderTargetBitmap for **RedGrid** it will return red colored rectangle as image

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition/>
       <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="RedGrid" Background="Red" Height="100" Width="100"></Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="WhiteGrid" Background="White" Height="100" Width="100"></Grid>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Render" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

//C# code

```
 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await rtb.RenderAsync(GridToBeRendered);

            var pixelBuffer = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
            var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
            var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
            StorageFolder myfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile file;
            file = await myfolder.CreateFileAsync("Render" + ".png", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            if (file != null)
            {
                using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
                    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                         BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                                         (uint)rtb.PixelWidth,
                                         (uint)rtb.PixelHeight,
                                         displayInformation.RawDpiX,
                                         displayInformation.RawDpiY,
                                         pixels);
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
            await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
        }
```

Comment: I know that. This is what I am actually doing for the moment. I have another control on top of it. However I want to have the element I want to capture a large size. I don't want to stretch the control that is on top, and don't want the window or scrollview to be larger to accommodate a large background.